# replacing all text strings with 0 and 1 in r

Tags: r, string, loops, regression

I am working on a school project. My df contains a lot of character strings. Would I would like to do for my regression analysis is to replace any row that has a string with 1 to imply that yes something happens and any row that is blank with 0 to imply that there is nothing there. For instance, a column is called indigenous and has many different language types for people that speak non common languages but for those that just speak english it is blank. What i would want to do is that for any column that is filled make it a 1 and any column that is blank make it a zero.

Comment: If the blank is `""` then use `+(df1$col != '')`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `nzchar`, e.g.,

```
> +nzchar(s)
[1] 1 0 1
```

**Data**

```
s <- c("abc","","volvo")
```

Comment: so i would do df$row <- +nzchar()?

Comment: @aped Yes, `df$row <- +nzchar(df$row)`